# ModuleNotFoundError with numpy inside virtual environment Python

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv

I have a recurrent problem which seems to be related to my terminal iTerm2 (3.3.7, the newest version). I'm on macOS.
I have created a virtual environement using the command

```
python3 -m venv /venv_name
```

From there, I have installed several packages (inside my virtual environment) using

```
pip install package_name
```

among which numpy, all pretty much standard (pandas, matplotlib...), for a project inside this virtual environment. When I don't quit me terminal and work inside my environment, everything works well and I have no problem at all.

However, if I quit the virtual environment and close my terminal, it happens very often (not always but almost every time) that I get the following error when trying to import numpy:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

This means that almost every time I want to work in the venv, I need to delete it, rebuilt it and import all the packages again.

I was wondering if someone had the same issue.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Do you use active file in your environment's to active and use the environment? In your question you said that you're using pip to install some package(s) but I wonder if you use the activate, each time you use your environment. https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Mac/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I activate the virtual environment before using pip, so that the pip used to install the packages is the one from the virtualenv

Comment: Check out this github issues last entry : https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12977

Comment: did you looked at git issues? like [this](https://github.com/alpacahq/pylivetrader/issues/73#issuecomment-455901124).

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. Apparently my numpy version is up to date, and it does not seem to be a PATH issue as well. My PATH inside the virtual env is the following : 

/Users/my_name/Documents/virtualenvs/venv_name/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Apple/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin


It seems ok to me, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Anyone has an idea ?